# jquery serialize a input array

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I tried to make a jQuery post call with a serialized input array like this:

```js
$.post(sub, {
  eventid: eventid,
  rowid: $('input[name^="rowid"]').serialize(),
  colid: $('input[name^="colid"]').serialize()
},
```

But on the Server side in PHP I get this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
array(3) {
  ["eventid"]=>
  string(3) "202"
  ["rowid"]=>
  string(41) "rowid%5B%5D=5&rowid%5B%5D=6&rowid%5B%5D=7"
  ["colid"]=>
  string(42) "colid%5B%5D=6&colid%5B%5D=13&colid%5B%5D=9"
}
```

How can I create a PHP array with the jquera post call?

Comment: Please add example HTML and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You only need the value from the input field.

So maybe you can try like this

```
$.post(sub, {
    eventid: eventid,
    rowid: $('input[name^="rowid"]').val(),
    colid: $('input[name^="colid"]').val()
});
```

If the value is complicated use JSON stringify, and parse with php.